# How to store \"> in a Swift string?

Tags: swift, special-characters, swift-playground, escaping

I'm trying to store \"> in a string. Theoretically, "\\" should print \ and "\"" does print ". However, when I try to print \ in a string using \ the output is a double forward slash:

```
var str = "\">" 
// ">
var str2 = "\\"
// \\ 
var str3 = "\\\">"
// \\">
var str4 = "\\">"
// escapes after quotation mark (error)
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how do I store \"> in a string?

Comment: by using `str3`.

Comment: that outputs \\">

Comment: I was looking at the output in playground and not printing to console. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `str3`. See for example:

```
var str3 = "\\\">"
str3.characters.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

> \
>   "
>   >

It does not matter what `str3` itself *outputs* in Xcode since Xcode can decide how to display strings. E.g. it decides to display the escaping character of `\`. It does *not* display the escape in front of `"` because in Playground for example the inner `"` is already differently colored that the `"` that actually delimit the string:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `str3` is right. For instance:

```
print("\\\">")
```

prints the desired sequence:

> \">

You might be confusing the *escaped* output, produced by Swift Playground, with the actual string. When in doubt, try the console :)

Comment: smack me for not printing to console and trusting the playground output on the right hand side... it shows \\">

Answer (score 1):

The playground output is wrong (or I do not understand it). `print()` gives you the correct output though:

```
var str3 = "\\\">"  // Plaground output:  \\">
print(str3)
```

prints: `\">`